# How to count how many Integer numbers are in a certain Range of Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I used `=INT(H4:I15)=H4:I15` to return a table of TRUE and FALSE if a number is an integer or not
And `=COUNTIF(J4:K15,TRUE)` to count how many return TRUE

I was wondering if there's any way around this so I don't have 2 columns with TRUE and FALSES in my sheet

Comment: Yes, there are a number of ways. Just to give a few ideas, you could use a SUMPRODUCT() formula, use Power Query, or use VBA to loop through the range or create a custom formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `SUM` across Boolean responses which can help to simplify the equation using the logic you already created to identify ints

```
=SUM(--(INT(A1:A12)=A1:A12))
```